# Errors while performing searches - SUPER SEARCH

Tags: supersearch

i am having a small problem with the super search add on. When i use a single word to perform a search everything is just fine; however when i try a sentence (children in need) for example i am getting lots of error messages in the header.

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Array to string conversion
Filename: libraries/super_search_lib.php
Line Number: 682

the above comes up about 100 times followed by

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/happysimon/webapps/adcs/system/codeigniter/system/core/Exceptions.php:170)
Filename: core/Common.php
Line Number: 475

You can try yourself at http://adcs.happytesting.co.uk/

Any idea anyone what could cause this messages?

Thanks

Kind Regards

Comment: ...You realize we can't see your errors and that it only reports when logged in as Super Admin? You have to set Debug Preference to 2 for all users to see those errors.

Comment: I too have just had this highlighted to me from a client. Two word search queries seem to be fine, but three word produce the errors. I assume you've got the latest version of SuperSearch installed (yet to check mine).

Comment: Here is what i got from the Supper Search Support team; AND IT WORKED...

Comment: I wasn't able to log into the CP, but I got in through FTP and managed to apply a fix.

I think there were two solutions here:
• Leave the Super Search code intact and turn off fuzzy searching, or
• In libraries/super_search_lib.php right above Line 682, add this:
if(is_array($word))
   {
    $word = implode($word, ' ');     
   }

This turns $word into a string if it isn't a string (thus the cause of the error). I applied the latter on your installation, but will note the issue to our developers.

Let us know if this works for you :)

Best regards,

Nicolas Bottari
Software Technical Support